# parse comma separated document

Tags: r, parsing

that contains comma separated data.

for instance:

```
arg1='1',arg2=c(1,2),arg3=3
```

Note that a priori I don't know the number of arguments

I would like to get a list of arguments with their values as elements of the list

```
$arg1   
1  

$arg2  
c(1,2)  

$arg3  
3
```

Comment: please don't put part of your question in the title (/. notwithstanding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that would be a good idea but you could use `eval` and `parse` for that, e.g.:

```
args <- readLines("args.txt", n=1)
l <- eval(parse(text=paste("list(", args, ")")))
l
#$arg1
#[1] "1"

#$arg2
#[1] 1 2

#$arg3
#[1] 3
```

Comment: thanks. Why would you not recommend to do that? What would be the limitations? A bit naively, i find it quite elegant

Comment: after reflexion, indeed I don't quite like the fact that everything is being evaluated. Eg if one of the argument is calling another function etc...

Comment: @RockScience I think part of the reason is that one should avoid having such a document format in the first place. Whence cometh it, and why use it instead of standard `R` tools for extracting `formals` from a function, or some such?

Comment: Agreed with your first statement. My problem here is that I would like to extract the exact argument values. I have one function but I want to retrieve the argument values used in several instance of this function.